# Как задать background с градиентом и картинкой

Tags: css3, css

То есть, как тут заменить `white`, на градиент

```
    background: url(../images/photo_slie.png) no-repeat 7px 9px white;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linear gradient - это и есть изображение, поэтому изображение надо прописывать через запятую

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients